# Compile using gcc without plain text constants in ELF image

Tags: gcc, constants, elf, plaintext

I have some string constants in a C code. when i compile it using gcc, the strings are stored in a.out in plain text. These can be hand-edited in a.out. I wan't them to be encoded in some format so that no one can change the strings by editing a.out. Are there any objcopy or gcc options to avoid this?

Comment: As long as a.out is editable they can always change the strings no matter how you encode them. Obfuscating the strings makes it slightly harder of course but you can never stop people entirely.

Answer (score 0):

is it then atleast possible to compile the code so that the elf executes only after an integrity self-check & terminate with an error if it fails...

that is it can store some kind of md5sum in the end, and check it at each execution..

i believe win32 apps have this, & hand-editing a windows exe , makes it an invalid win32 app, because the checksum fails..

is this possible in GCC/Linux ?